# TWI/I2C Protocol with HMC5883L Magnetometer with ATMEGA256RFR2 XPLAINED PRO (megaavr)

Tags: arduino, atmega, i2c, magnetometer, twi

Im trying to read Data Output Registers of X,Y,Z

So far I've been able to:

```
Send a START - flag 0x08 = START condition transmitted.
Send 0x3C - flag 0x18 = SLA+W transmitted, ACK received.
//For configuring HMC5883L Control Register A & B
Send 0x02 data byte - flag 0x28 = Data byte transmitted, ACK received.
Send 0x00 data byte - flag 0x28 = Data byte transmitted, Ack Received.
Send a Repeat Start - flag 0x10 = Repeat Start condition transmitted.
Send 0x3D - flag 0x40 = SLA+R transmitted, ACK received.

Start > SLA+W > Configure Control Register A & B > Repeat Start > SLA+R > ??
```

I'm stuck on what to do after sending a SLA+R, I've tried sending a 0x03 (MSB register for Output X). I keep getting a repeated fixed value like (0,10,10,18 - repeat).

My main question would be how do I correctly read the memory address of the slave at 0x03 followed by 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 successfully?

In the data sheet it is mentioned:

> When one or more of the output registers are read, new data cannot be
>   placed in any of the output data registers until all six data output
>   registers are read.
>
> To minimize the communication between the master and this device, the
>   address pointer updated automatically without master intervention. The
>   register pointer will be incremented by 1 automatically after the
>   current register has been read successfully.
>
> The address pointer value itself cannot be read via the I2C bus. Any
>   attempt to read an invalid address location returns 0’s, and any write
>   to an invalid address location or an undefined bit within a valid
>   address location is ignored by this device.
>
> To move the address pointer to a random register location, first issue
>   a “write” to that register location with no data byte following the
>   commend. For example, to move the address pointer to register 10, send
>   0x3C 0x0A.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To move the address pointer to a random register location, **first issue
>   a “write” to that register location with no data byte** following the
>   commend. For example, to move the address pointer to register 10, send
>   0x3C 0x0A

So, to read from register 0x03 on, try:

```
Start > SLA+W > 0x03 > Repeat Start > SLA+R > read 6x
```

(Notice the `W` in the first `SLA+W`.)

Answer (score 0):

Ive actually solved the issue, but another weird issue is: when I write to 0x03 (to set the pointer), I'm not exactly sure wheres the pointer, but it reads 0x04 instead. To fix it, I started from 0x02, they it worked perfectly. I verified this by reading ID register A,B,C. Reading the first ID at 0x0A gave me a '4' when I was supposed to get a 'H'. So to rectify this, i actually started reading from 0x09, then it gave me a 'H', '4', '3'.

Comment: Note that you must *not* actually write any data. Just write one byte -the register number- and then switch to reading.